# How do I disable the PC speaker (beep) on Debian (Buster)?

Tags: debian, gnome, kernel-modules

The [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker#Disable_PC_Speaker) says how to blacklist the pc-speaker module.
But that does not work with debian. Can anybody please help me?

PS: Small concretion: I am using Gnome and would like to silence the beep coming from some entries in the Gnome Terminal window.

Comment: Can you show your blacklist entry? Also check if it is loaded. You can do this with $ lsmod and search for pcspkr.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, can you tell me what is a "concretion"?

Answer (score 4):

In Debian, the PC speaker support is built into the main kernel, as opposed to being a separate loadable module like in Arch. But the other methods mentioned in the Arch wiki should still work.

If you're using your system in text mode, `setterm -blength 0` sets the default beep length to 0 ms, effectively silencing it. You'll need to add this to your login script to make it persistent for you, or set up a `systemd` service like this to silence it at boot time for everyone:

```
[Unit]
Description=Silence virtual console default beep

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Environment=TERM=linux
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/console
ExecStart=/usr/bin/setterm -blength 0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Put that in a text file named e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/silence-console.service`. Then run `systemctl daemon-reload; systemctl enable silence-console; systemctl start silence-console` and it should take effect immediately and also on subsequent reboots.

For X11 GUI sessions, create this very simple X11 session start-up script:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -b
```

Put that in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/91custom-silence-beep` to make it take effect for everyone at the next GUI login.

Depending on which X11 desktop environment/window manager you're using, it might override any low-level settings made with `xset`. But if it does that, it should also have its own ways to control the beep.

For example, the GNOME Terminal has its own setting. Select the Edit menu of the Terminal window, select Preferences, find "Unnamed" under Profiles, and on the Text tab, uncheck "Terminal bell".

Or if you want to change the terminal bell to a visual one, you could run these commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences visual-bell-type frame-flash
```

If you want a more noticeable visual bell, you can use `fullscreen-flash` instead of `frame-flash`.

Comment: Well - thanks for the extensive and fast answer. It does not help. Sorry.

Small concretion: I am using Gnome and would like to silence the beep coming from some entries in the Gnome Terminal window.

Comment: You should have said so in the first place! :-) Please see my edit.